# Package not found when installing with dnu install. Works with dnu restore

Tags: .net, dnx, dnu

I'm trying to `dnu install 
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting 1.1.1` but it fails with 
**Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting
  Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)**
Doing `dnu restore` with a project.json file including the same package in its dependencies list works fine:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "ScriptSharp.ScriptEngine Class Library",
  "frameworks": {
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting": "1.1.1"
  }
}
```

This is the list of feeds used:
https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
https://www.myget.org/F/roslyn-nightly/
https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2
https://www.myget.org/F/dotnet-corefx/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After installing the CoreCLR 1.0 runtime it worked: 
`dnvm install -r coreclr -arch x86 latest -u`